# Problemas com crontab e script Git push

Tags: github, script, bash, cron

Criei um scrip .sh para atualizar meu repositório no Git Hub. Manualmente o scrip roda perfeitamente.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/tmp/
git init
git add .
git commit -m "`date +'%Y_%m_%d'`"
git push --force origin main
```

A crontab roda e gera um log chamado cronlog.txt. Conteúdo do log é:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/user/tmp/.git/
```

Ou seja, a cron executa o script em parte, mas não por completo.

Agradeço eventuais auxílios

Comment: Em qual `crontab` está agendada a execução de seu script? Se não for com o usuário `root`, pode testar logado no usuário em que ela foi configurada?

Comment: No usuário em que ela foi configurada está funcionando perfeitamente. O usuário é `user`. Testei na `crontab` desse usuário e via `sudo crontab -e`. Em ambos acontece a mesma situação. Inicializa o Git e não termina o script. Manualmente, tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Parece que a pergunta [How to correctly add 'git push' command to crontab - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368504/how-to-correctly-add-git-push-command-to-crontab-ubuntu) tem um caso bem similar ao seu.

Comment: Sim, eu já tentei a solução proposta por eles e não deu certo. Em outro servidor roda tudo corretamente, em outra conta Git Hub, por óbvio.

Comment: Se em outra conta do Gh roda, verifique as permissões novamente: usuárío, chave SSH, o que for... pois parece ser o caso

Comment: Você está tentando inicializar um projeto, sendo que ele já existe.